# What role does requirements play in generating test cases for white box testing?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, requirements-validation, istqb

I'm currently preparing for an exam on software quality assurance. By looking through slides and [ISTQB material](http://istqbexamcertification.com/what-is-white-box-or-structure-based-or-structural-testing-techniques/), I got to the question: "which role the requirements play in white-box testing?"

Of course, for black-box testing it is quite clear, there I would write tests by just looking at the requirements/specifications and test whether the software does comply to these. But, for white-box testing, how much should I look at the requirements and should white-box test-cases be based on requirements at all? Or, should they primarily aim to achieve high code coverage?

Answer (score 2):

### White-box Testing

White box testing is a testing technique, that examines the program structure and derives test data from the program logic/code. The other names of glass box testing are clear box testing, open box testing, logic driven testing or path driven testing or structural testing.

**White-box Testing related requirement**

- UNDERSTAND THE SOURCE CODE
- CREATE TEST PLAN AND EXECUTE
- CREATE TEST CASES AND EXECUTE

**White-box Testing Techniques**

**Unit Testing**
     In unit testing, use one by one modules and test sub-module.Unit testing is performed on each unit or block of code as it is developed.Unit testing is essentially done by the programmer.

**Verify in White Box Testing**

- Basically verify the security holes in the code.
- Verify the broken or incomplete paths in the code.
- Verify the flow of structure mention in the specification document.
- Verify the Expected outputs.
- Verify the all conditional loops in the code to check the complete functionality of the application.
- Verify the line by line or Section by Section in the code & cover the 100% testing.

[image]

Comment: I doubt if this answers the question of the OP

Comment: Actually it isn't. I know what white box testing is. What I want to know is which role the requirements, specified in the beginning of a project, play in generating test cases for white box testing. I edited the title, maybe that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think the white-box Test Cases should be generated based on Design Specifications rather than Requirements Documentation.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) says White Box Testing :

> is a method of testing software that tests internal structures or workings of an application, as opposed to its functionality.

So, to test the internal structure of an application, Design Specifications (as they usually contain information how the logic are implemented and the internal structure of the applications) would be of more use than Requirements Documentation.